# Which library does DBCombo come from?

Tags: dll, vb5

I'm having some compatibility issues with a legacy VB5 program I inherited.

Specifically, the `DBCombo` control.

Where does this control come from? I think it might be from the Microsoft DAO Object Library but I want to make sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is, well, was, an ActiveX control last seen in VB6.  The DLL that supported it was named "DBList32.ocx".  If you have a really old machine on which it was installed then you could copy that file from the c:\windows\system32 directory and register it with regsvr32.exe.

I can still add it to the VS2008 .NET toolbox by right-clicking it and selecting Choose Items, COM tab and ticking "Microsoft DBCombo Control" (got VB6 installed on the machine).  Didn't actually try to use it, odds are low after the Windows 7 SP1 update for ADO that broke backwards compatibility.